# Riley Loves You

Tags: riddle

> My prefix is in water
>
> As it moves along
>
> My infix a gaming console,
>
> That you and I can play
>
> Well, you see…
>
> I can’t really, um.. describe, uh
>
> My suffix is, you know, hard to explain…
>
> But all together, you see me all around
>
> And come in all different colors

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like

> Flower

My prefix is in water
As it moves along

> Flow

My infix a gaming console,
That you and I can play

> We because Wii and you and I.

Well, you see…
I can’t really, um.. Describe, uh
My suffix is, em hard to explain…

> Er because you use it to try and say something.

But all together, you see me all around
And come in all different colors

> Flower

Title

> when you pick petals off of a flower to see if someone loves you.

Comment: The "D" being capitalized has nothing to do with it

Comment: I edited my answer. Is this better @PotatoLatte? :)

Comment: This is correct!